# Reset html required style with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, required

I have a form with an input with the attribute required set. When i submit the form and the input is empty, it shows a red border around it.

I am now looking for a javascript method to remove this, and reset the display of the input to the initial state.

After resetting and submitting again, the input should be checked again and show a red border if empty. Therefore i think setting css with :required does not give the desired solution.

A quick fiddle to illustrate my question:

```js
jQuery(function() {
  jQuery('#reset').click(function() {
    //Clear red border of input
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="myform">
  <input id="myinput" required>
  <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
<button id="reset">reset</button>
```

After clicking reset, the form should be shown as when the page is just loaded.

**Edit**
I tested this in firefox. In chrome the style automatically is removed when the element is onfocussed. However, i am still looking for a js solution to remove the message.

Comment: _"When i submit the form and the input is empty, it shows a red border around it."_ How is red border applied to element? At `css`, or `js`? Can you include `css` at Question?, create stacksnippets to demonstrate? Should `input` element have `value` attribute?

Comment: @pomber Firefox, i see now that in chrome the border is removed when unfocussing.

Comment: @guest271314 Red border is automatically added in firefox. There is no more css or js than i put here. And the input element should not have a value attribute.

Comment: You can use `css` `:focus`, `:invalid`. _"However, i am still looking for a js solution to remove the message"_ What do you mean by "remove the message"?

Comment: @guest271314 When submitted, it shows a message like "This field is required". This is removed when i unfocuss, but i am looking for a js method to remove that message.

Comment: @user4493177 _"This is removed when i unfocuss, but i am looking for a js method to remove that message."_ You can use `.setCustomValidity()` at `invalid` event, see updated post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit, Updated

> I want to reset the style, not prevent it from happening (when i dont
>   focus on it).

You can add a `className` to `#myinput` element which sets `box-shadow` to `none` and `border` to `inherit` at `click` on `#reset` element. Remove `className` at `focus` or `change` event on `#myinput` element, depedning on whether you want the `box-shadow` and `border` removed at `focus` on invalid input, or when user inputs a value.

```
.reset:-moz-ui-invalid:not(output) {
  box-shadow: none;
  border: 1px solid inherit;
}
```

---

> When submitted, it shows a message like "This field is required". This
>   is removed when i unfocuss, but i am looking for a js method to remove
>   that message.

You can use `invalid` event, `.setCustomValidity(" ")` with a space character as parameter, called on `event.target` within handler.

---

You can use `css` `:focus`, `:invalid` to set `border` to `red` only when `input` gains focus and input is invalid. At `html` can add `pattern` attribute with `RegExp` `\w+` to set `input` to invalid if value of input is empty string or only space characters

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery("#reset").click(function() {
    jQuery("#myinput").addClass("reset")
  });
  jQuery("#myinput").focus(function() {
    jQuery(this).removeClass("reset")
  })
  .on("invalid", function(e) {
    e.target.setCustomValidity(" ");
  })
})
```

```css
#myinput:focus:invalid {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
#myinput:focus {
  outline: none;
}
.reset:-moz-ui-invalid:not(output) {
  box-shadow: none;
  border: 1px solid inherit;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="myform">
  <input id="myinput" pattern="\w+" type="text" value="" required/>
  <input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
<button id="reset">reset</button>
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but this does not do what i am looking for. I want to reset the style, not prevent it from happening (when i dont focus on it).

Comment: @user4493177 See updated post. Appears to return expected result in at `webkit` browsers and nightly

Answer (score 1):

I cannot reproduce it here. But probably your problem is the [pseudo-class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:invalid) applied to the input.
Given that you cannot remove pseudo-classes, maybe you can override the style. Something like:

```
:invalid {
  box-shadow: none;
}

:-moz-submit-invalid {
  box-shadow: none;
}

:-moz-ui-invalid {
  box-shadow:none;
}
```

If you just need to apply the style when the reset button is clicked, add the styles to your own class and add/remove the class when needed.

Answer (score 0):

The `initial` keyword makes a CSS property take the browser's default style, if this is what you're looking for...

```js
jQuery(function() {
  jQuery('#reset').click(function() {
    //Clear red border of input
    jQuery('#myinput').css('border-color', 'initial');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">
 #myinput {
  border-color: red;
 }
</style>
<form id="myform">
  <input id="myinput" required>
  <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
<button id="reset">reset</button>
```